# How to print a barcode using print server?

Tags: java, printing

Actually, I wanted to connect with the printer through the print server. I have written some code but I'm unable to connect with the specific printer of that print server.

Note: I'm able to connect and print data on the printer using direct IP but as we wanted to select specific printer from the print server we need to use Public IP.

Is there any way to connect with the printer from the print server?
I would be so grateful if you share something on it.

```
public static void main (String argv[]) throws Exception
   {
       // The line below illustrates the default port 6101 for `enter code here`mobile printers 9100 is the default port number
       // for desktop and tabletop printers
       try{
           Socket clientSocket=new Socket("172.xx.xx.xxx",6101);//(host,port)
           
           DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
outToServer.writeBytes("^XA");
           outToServer.writeBytes("^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FD Test Print");
           outToServer.writeBytes("^FS");
           outToServer.writeBytes("^XZ");
           
           clientSocket.close();
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Do you get any exceptions thrown? If so, add them to your question with a full stack trace. What do you mean by "unable to connect"? What exactly happens?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies

As we trying to print from a specific printer we first need connect with that printer (In my case we have printer server with almost 20 printers) then we can send print data.

So here we need an idea for how to connect with that specific printer using public IP as I'm able to connect using direct IP.